# I want to empty one column, but I want to keep the header name in unix

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, columns

I am using below command to empty the column but I want to keep the header row, how can I do it in the same command?

```
awk -F "," '{$10="";}1' OFS="," InputFile.csv > test.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish with the following:

```
awk -F, 'NR != 1{$10=""}1' OFS=, InputFile.csv > test.csv
```

This will skip any actions on the first line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed -e 's/[^,]*//10' input.file
```

Will null the 10th field in the input file.

Answer (score -1):

```
I Done by below method tested  and it worked fine too

    awk -F "," 'NR >1{$10="";}1' OFS="," InputFile.csv > test.csv



Tested and it worked fine too
```

Comment: Let me know the reason for down vte